# Right of Appeal for UK Visit Visa Refused

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I, together with my filipina friend made the above Application for UK Visit Visa which was refused on grounds which in my opinion are both groundless and incorrect.

1. Decision maker refused under Appendix V 4.2 (a) and (c), because she was a non-return/flight risk because she doesn't show sufficient ties to her home.

Apart from coming from a good home and family with whom she resides, she clearly showed in her passport many previous overseas visits for holidays and recreation purposes, including several to Australia.

My Invitation Letter undertakes that my guest would return on time and comply with all the conditions pertaining; including those of Part 1 para 35 of the Rules., that she and I would obey all laws, rules and regulations.

2. The decision maker also refused under Appendix V4.2 (e) stating he was not satisfied my guest had sufficient funds, referring to her bank statement, provided only for completeness against the list of required documents.

In fact the application was based upon my Invitation Letter states clearly I am paying for everything, and my own bank statements showing substantial income and bank balances.  Decision maker disregarded this. So Citing V4.2 (e) is inaccurate since the appropriate clause is V4.3 wherein we have already undertaken full compliance.

Do we really have no way of referring this back to UK Visa as stated on the Refusal Notice?

Comment: Does your friend have a job in her home country? And were you able to show a credible reason for your invitation? E.g. you’ve met in person and you’ve visited her in her home country previously?

Comment: Previous behaviour (returning to The Philippines) is no guarantee for future behaviour, so if the officer evaluating the application found a reason to disregard it he/she can. If your promise to pay for everything, gave the officer the idea that you might be in some kind of romantic relationship, it might even have given him/her that reason. (That is just speculation on my part, don't hold it against anybody). So saying that the refusal is groundless is a failure on your part. And why has she bought a non-return flight?

Comment: Are you saying that a possible romantic relationship would be grounds to refuse?  There has been no ticket purchase at all and no intention to not return.

Comment: @Graham Thurston A possible romantic relationship that is grounded in having met face-to-face, with evidence of an ongoing, credible, relationship (eg visits by you to your friend) can be an acceptable premise for a visit to the U.K. (I’ve succeeded in this myself). But an online ‘relationship’ with no face-to-face contact is highly likely to be a red flag as far a a premise for a visit goes - after all, U.K. citizens can generally travel easily to most places.And even a credible relationship does not remove the need for the applicant to demonstrate close ties to home, typically a job & family

Comment: "My Invitation Letter undertakes that my guest would return on time and comply with all the conditions pertaining" This has no evidential weight at all. You can't compel her to leave and, look, who's going to write a letter saying, "Actually, I think she might break the law but please let her in anyway"? Everyone will promise that their visitor will obey the law .

Comment: @Traveller, thank you, yes, we met originally on line and later we met in person, had a great holiday of several weeks and have continued the friendship. All explained to ECO.

Comment: @Graham Thurston Then perhaps a) you applied too soon (I was able to prove a 5 year history, with me visiting at least twice a year in the meantime); and/or b) the showstopper is your friend’s lack of a job and savings in her home country (both of which we could prove); and/or c) insufficient close family ties (ie a child and/or dependent elderly parents (we proved this too).

Answer (score 2):

> **Do we really have no way of referring this back to UK Visa as stated on the Refusal Notice?**

I believe you'd have to show that the ECO ignored provided evidence. Usually the refusal letter states exactly what evidence the ECO considered. Often they say something to the effect that, even though someone else is paying for everything the ECO is required to make a decision based on the financial and personal circumstances of the applicant. Note that the ECOs don't make the rules. Disliking those rules is not grounds for an appeal.

- See [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) - if your friend's refusal letter is substantially different, post it here after blacking out any personal information.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide very useful additional guidance. The letter was not substantially different although it banged on about her almost zero and unused bank account.  It did NOT cite anything in regard to my invitation or sponsorship. Another comment provided above suggests they suspect a romantic association.  I don't understand how that can be a negative factor. But if you can say that they have not taken papers into consideration, yes, that is the case.